# do we need two bitmaps for 2 different ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview

I need to know whether there is need to set two bitmaps for displaying images in two ImageViews. I am uploading images from gallery .

code:-

```
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
       // Decode image size
       BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

       // The new size we want to scale to
       final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

       // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
       int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
       int scale = 1;
       while (true) {
           if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
               break;
           width_tmp /= 2;
           height_tmp /= 2;
           scale *= 2;
       }

       // Decode with inSampleSize
       BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       o2.inSampleSize = scale;
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
                   //first image i have uploaded by using first button
       imgView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       imgView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


   }
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking whether it is possible to assign one image resource to more than one ImageView?

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser no I am assigning different image resources to 2 different imageview. They will be uploaded using 2 different buttons.

Comment: You are setting the same bitmap to two different imageViews.

Comment: @Lunchbox ok , how to set different bitmaps for 2 imageviews.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question isn't very clear, from reading the comments I understand that you might be wanting to set different bitmaps to two ImageViews. If that is the case, here is how you do it:

```
firstBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

secondBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(someOtherPath, o2);
```